# Website loads slowly with www prefix, but https://[domain].com loads fine

Tags: domain, www

My organization switched over to networksolutions for domain hosting, and since then I've been having issues with slow load times.

When I enter the domain: https://www.martinsrestaurants.com the TTFB is very high (10+ seconds), regardless of a cleared or uncleared cache. The root https://martinsrestaurants.com works fine (< 2 seconds).

The site was constructed on wordpress, and there are some errors from outdated plugins, yet none appear critical.

The www A record links to the host IP.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this would be happening. I assume the time is a result of a failed/slow redirect, but I have no idea what the potential solution could be.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: "The www A record links to the host IP."  This might be an opportunity to use a different record type.  https://support.dnsimple.com/articles/differences-between-a-cname-alias-url/

Answer (score 2):

`https://www.martinsrestaurants.com` redirects to `https://martinsrestaurants.com`. This redirect takes 6 seconds.

This is *probably* due to some misconfiguration on the webserver that serves the redirect. I would suggest that you talk with the hosting provider.